# Transfer ownership of Cloud9 environment

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

Is it possible to transfer ownership of an AWS Cloud9 environment? How do I do that?

I can't find any documentation about that. Not sure if it's supported or not.

Comment: Isn't it a paid service? Shouldn't they have support? I would ask the provider of a service first and not a developer forum.

Comment: What do you mean by "transfer ownership"? If you mean "move it to a different AWS Account", then this is not possible. Or do you want to give it to a different user within the _same_ AWS Account?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I want to give it to a different IAM user within the same AWS Account. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that *"An owner has full control over an environment. Each environment has one and only one owner"*.

You can 'share' your environment with other users, but *"You cannot remove your user from an environment if you're the environment owner"*. Therefore, you need to make somebody else the 'owner' first. It doesn't explicitly say how this is done, but it appears that **granting a user Read+Write access makes them equivalent to the Owner**. (Try it, and let us know what you find!)

Also note: *"For EC2 environments, read/write members can use the environment owner's AWS access credentials, instead of their own credentials, to make calls from the environment to AWS services."*

See: [Working with shared environment in AWS Cloud9 - AWS Cloud9](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/share-environment.html)

Comment: My use case was to grant permissions to other users so that they can share the environment as well. This role is exclusively for owner (manage member, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloud9/latest/user-guide/share-environment.html) and there is no way to transfer the ownership of an environment. I guess it's better to create a new environment for the other users.